# MSSQL Geometry/Geography types with JDBC fails with class [B?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, spatial

Looking at the sample here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/spatial-data-types-sample?view=sql-server-ver15

This sample works fine but normally if I want to stick to regular JDBC I would use

```
pstmt.setObject(1, geomWKT);
pstmt.setObject(2, geogWKT);
```

instead of

```
   pstmt.setGeometry(1, geomWKT);
   pstmt.setGeography(2, geogWKT);
```

which works.

But then if I want to get the objects back I would use:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from " + tableName);
rs.next();
rs.getObject(1)
```

instead of

```
SQLServerResultSet rs = (SQLServerResultSet) stmt.executeQuery("select * from " + tableName);
rs.next();
rs.getGeometry(1)
```

This doesn't work. since rs.getObject() returns something with a class name [B instead of com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Geometry

Here's the full error:
class [B cannot be cast to class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Geometry ([B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Geometry is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Any ideas why? Same JDBC driver.

Comment: Class [B is a byte array, which is probably the default type to be returned based on JDBC requirements. Have you tried `getObject(1, Geometry.class)`?

Comment: I get "The conversion to class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Geometry is unsupported." :( I created an issue on their github site.  It seems its related to the module system.